# If $(x-r)$ is a repeating factor of the polynomial $f(x)=0$ repeating $m$ times, how many times does it repeat for $f'(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polynomials, common-root

This is the question in my book: if $x-r$ is a factor of the polynomial
$$
f(x) = a_{n}x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \ldots + a_0
$$
repeated $m$ times, then $r$ is a root of $f'(x)=0$ repeated how many times?

This is the answer given: $x=r$ is root of $f'(x)=0$ repeated $(m-1)$ times.
How did they reach this conclusion? Is there some theorem that explains this?

Comment: Hint:  the assumption is equivalent to saying that $f(x)=(x-r)^mg(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial such that $g(r)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=g(x)h(x)$$
$$g(x)=(x-r)^m\rightarrow g'(x)=m(x-r)^{m-1}$$
Product rule:
$$f'(x)=(x-r)^mh'(x)+m(x-r)^{m-1}h(x)$$
$$\rightarrow f'(x)=(x-r)^{m-1}[(x-r)h'(x)+mh(x)]$$
So $x=r$ is the root of $f'(x)$ $m-1$ times as the question states